# How to find the mass of the solute given a concentration as a mass fraction?

Tags: stoichiometry, concentration

> Formalin is a $37\%~\mathrm{W/W}$ solution of methanal in water. What mass of water must be added to $250~\mathrm{g}$ of methanal to make formalin.

Here's what I've done so far. It's wrong though. According to my book answer is $430~\mathrm{g}$ $\ce{H2O}$.

$$\frac{Cw}{w} = \frac{\mathrm{m\ solute}}{\mathrm{m\ solution}} \cdot 100\%$$

$$37 \% = \mathrm{\frac{m\ solute}{250} \cdot 100\ \%}$$

$$\mathrm{\frac{37}{100} = \frac{m\ solute}{250}}$$

$$\mathrm{0.37 \cdot 250 = m\ solute}$$

$$\mathrm{m\ solute = 92.5\ g}$$

Where have I went wrong? Am I completely off or at least close?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have been given a [mass fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_fraction_(chemistry)), $w_{\ce{CH2O}}=37\%~\mathrm{w/w}$, and the mass of the solute, $m_{\ce{CH2O}}=250~\mathrm{g}$. You calculated the mass of the solution wrong.
The mass fraction is defined as
$$w_i = \frac{m_i}{m}\tag1$$
with $m$ being the total mass and therefore
$$m = \sum_i m_i.$$
The latter is also the mass of your solution, the sum of the solute and the solvent.
$$m=m_{\ce{H2O}}+m_{\ce{CH2O}} = m_{\ce{H2O}} + 250~\mathrm{g}$$
Substitute what you know into $(1)$ and transform:
\begin{align}
w_{\ce{CH2O}} &= \frac{m_{\ce{CH2O}}}{m_{\ce{H2O}}+m_{\ce{CH2O}}}\\
0.37 &= \frac{250~\mathrm{g}}{m_{\ce{H2O}} + 250~\mathrm{g}}\\
m_{\ce{H2O}} &= \frac{250~\mathrm{g}}{0.37}-250~\mathrm{g} = 426~\mathrm{g}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems. In your equation, you've written the mass of the solution is 250 g, but there is 250 g of methanal and the total mass of the solution is 250 g + $m_{\ce{H2O}}$.

Second, the solution is 37% methanal not 37% water so the you've written the equation, you're solving for the wrong thing.

These should help you get on track:

$$\begin{align}\\
f_\mathrm{meth} &= \frac{m_\mathrm{meth}}{m_\mathrm{solution}}\\
m_\mathrm{solution}&=m_\mathrm{meth}+m_\mathrm{\ce{H2O}}\\
\%_\mathrm{meth} &= f_\mathrm{meth}\times100\%
\end{align}$$